# transformer's basic operation

Tags: transformer, basic

[image]

1. Doesn't the induced voltage (v1) suppose to oppose i1 flow, so + and- should be inverted?
   [image]
2. Is it possible for the same transformer that v1/v2=-a and i2/i1=a (for example if it is possible to reverse direction of i2) ?

Comment: If you're asking about your homework, please show your work so far. We'll *help* **YOU** solve it, but we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: something looks like similar to your test paper...

Comment: @Andyaka are they incorrect? The windings are in opposite directions.

Comment: Also, please don't beat up on a question just because it has a textbook. The OP isn't looking for the answers, just some help understanding. If you ever read something in a textbook that you didn't understand immediately, you aren't allowed to downvote.

Comment: @PhilFrost Yeah.... No you are quite correct - I'll delete my false observation. Taking a second look... yeah I'm wrong D'oh. BTW I never downvoted.

Comment: It would be nice if this question had a preface, something like "I have the following homework material, but I don't quite understand A and B." I think it's likely someone viewing this thinks the questions are ripped straight from the textbook, when in fact, they aren't. These are decent questions, they are just presented poorly. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are looking at the circuit from the perspective of the mathematics or the engineering. If Circuit 1 is an ideal voltage source and Circuit 2 is a resistive load, the voltages and currents are shown as you would expect. The primary voltage *does* oppose the primary current flow as it is drawn. At the secondary, with a resistive load the current is an *effect* of the induced secondary voltage, so it does not oppose the secondary voltage.

If I were doing the maths of solving this for some particular source and some particular load, I would draw the i2 arrow in the opposite direction since it makes the equations easier to remember. *But the directions of the arrows are purely hypothetical when you are doing the maths*. In the case of a resistive load, I would get a negative sign in the expression for i2.

In *general*, the '+' and '-' signs for the voltages are there to tell us the sense of the windings (and as it happens we can see this from the way the windings are drawn) but they don't imply that the voltages are in-phase. The signs of the currents tell us nothing either because we don't know what the two circuits are. For all we know, "Circuit 2" might be a generator and Circuit 1 a load.